# How to set maxHeight over DimensionRatio with ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to display an image centered in parent with a dimension ratio of 1220:1000 AND a maximum height of 300dp (to keep the image small even with large screen)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1220:1000"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="200dp"  ==> This line break the ratio (the image is not displayed)
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `app:layout_constraintHeight_max` property break the ratio.
Is there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to enforce `max_height` and keep the dimension ratio at the same time, you need to constrain the width based on height. You can achieve that by adding `W` to your ratio:

`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1220:1000"`

This will constrain the height first and then set the width accordingly to satisfy the ratio.

More info on how this dimension ratio works can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#ratio).

Comment: It works like a charm :) `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1220:1000"` with `app:layout_constraintHeight_max="300dp"`

Comment: It looks like in ConstraintLayout `2.0.3` you must use `H` in place of `W` 

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the area with a dimension ratio and a max height, but you don't know if width or height is going to be adjusted, better don't to use `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` + `layout_constraintHeight_max`. They don't work well together.

Here I put my solution in the case you have an image 16:9 which will use full width while max height is not yet reached, otherwise it will respect max height, and width will be adjusted:

[image: aspect ratio + max height sample]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- This space view makes ImageView expands to its corresponding height -->
        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageview" />

        <com.a3.sgt.ui.widget.AspectRatioImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:dominantMeasurement="height"
            app:aspectRatioEnabled="true"
            app:aspectRatio="1.778"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="400dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/placeholder_glacier"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I used a custom `ImageView` I had in [my gist](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/2701930491c46bd615d5) which adjusts to aspect ratio, in order to avoid using `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` which causes the problem together with `layout_constraintHeight_max`

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to add the tag maxHeight?

```
android:maxHeight="200dp"
```