# android - ConstraintLayout: Using both DimensionRatio and Height_min

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I tried using both `layout_constraintDimensionRatio` and the `layout_constraintHeight_min` attributes of a view inside a `ConstraintLayout`, like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawerHeaderBg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="120dp"
    ... />
```

So I want it to first set the height according to the width (using the ratio) and then if it's smaller than `120dp`, set it to `120dp`. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208990/7581708) (and I set the ratio to `W,16:9` and also `H,16:9`) but that didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that maximized the view, that is definitely not what I want.